# AngularJS : Factories update variables

Tags: angularjs, promise, factory

I need to update the variable `notifications` from my factory after the promise is resolved.
The idea is to to call it like this:

```
InboxNotificationFactory.notifications
```

and this will return 0, and then when the promise is resolved it will update to some other value without the need to used `.then()` inside my controller.

```
inboxApp.factory('InboxNotificationFactory', function (inboxHttpService) {
    getNotifications();

    return {
        notifications: 0
    };

    function getNotifications() {
        inboxHttpService.totalUnreadMessages().then(function(response) {
            //ERROR RIGHT HERE
            this.notifications = response.data;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.notifications` doesn't exist.  Something like this is probably closer to what you want:

```
inboxApp.factory('InboxNotificationFactory', function (inboxHttpService) {
    var notifications = 0;

    inboxHttpService.totalUnreadMessages().then(function(response) {
        notifications = response.data;
    });

    return {
        notifications: notifications
    };
});
```